# Strange UINavigationBar behavior on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I am working on a personal project and in the process of feeling out a possible navigation flow of the app.

I am using UIPageViewController to switch between multiple view controllers.

The issue I am seeing only happens on iPhone 6 Plus. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, when I swipe from one view controller to the "next" one, the navigation bar of the "next" view controller appears to be 20 point shorter then what it should be (status bar present). When it fully loads, the height jumps to its correct size.

This happens only on iPhone 6 Plus and only on the initial launch.

Any insight / help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this I suppose (now that I got it working).

The simplest solution is to set the frame of the pageViewController.view to account for the status bar.

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 20.0)
```

And since this is all I needed in my particular situation, I am pretty happy with the result.

Another solution would involve setting up (adding) constraints programmatically on the view to which you are adding pageViewController.view.

```
    override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    self.pageViewController.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.pageViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.pageViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.pageViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.pageViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
}
```

The above example overrides updateViewConstraints() function.

Hope this helps someone along the way. If there is a better solution, please let me know.

Thanks!